# Remove rows whose values in one column do not fall in the range `[0,1]`

Tags: r, matrix

I'm working with a large amount of data stored in a matrix and I'd like to remove all rows whose values in one column do not fall in the range `[0,1]`. If the matrix is `M` (just an example of a 3 by 3 matrix), I tried with this code

```
m<-matrix(c(1,0,2,0.7,0.8,0.5,-0.6,0.11,0.4),3,3)
      [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]    1  0.7 -0.60
[2,]    0  0.8  0.11
[3,]    2  0.5  0.40
```

For this example I should remove the first and third rows. The only solution that comes to mind is based on for loops and

```
for(i in 1:n){
  array[i]<-sum(m[i,]<0, na.rm=TRUE)+sum(m[i,]>1, na.rm=TRUE)
}
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  if (array[i]!=0){
    m<-m[-i,]
    array<-array[-i]
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could compare the values of the matrix elementwise directly and create a logical matrix and select the rows accordingly using `rowSums`

```
m[rowSums(m <= 1 & m >= 0) == ncol(m), ]
#[1] 0.00 0.80 0.11
```

Or another way to do the same thing

```
m[rowSums(m > 1 | m < 0) == 0, ]
```

---

For both the above versions we can also use `apply` row-wise with `margin = 1` to subset the data

```
m[apply(m <= 1 & m >= 0, 1, all), ]
m[!apply(m > 1 | m < 0, 1, any), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also a possibility:

```
m[apply(m, 2, function(x) all(x >= 0) & all(x <= 1)), ]

[1] 0.00 0.80 0.11
```